# Invalid regular expression HTML Pattern

Tags: html, regex

This is my Regex:

```
pattern="[^\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\'\|\"]{8}"
pattern="[^!#$%^&*'|"]{8}"
```

How is this invalid in my HTML input tag? I want this symbols to be restricted in my `textbox`

```
<input placeholder="Something" type="text" required autofocus ng-model="someData" pattern="[^\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\'\|\"]{8}">
```

Comment: your regex is fine..is there any error?

Comment: yes the error is Invalid regular expression..

Comment: hmmm. with all honesty I don't know how to use the jsfiddle, but, I just want to allow anything except the following symbols ^!#$%^&*'|

Comment: is this the first caret or the caret before the ampersand

Comment: oops sorry.i didn't see it

Comment: i used http://ideone.com/jGHeQm to validate [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)..Its working without `required autofocus ng-model="someData"`. It seems you don't need to escape any of them in regex

Comment: You need to escape the quotation mark for the HTML processor, not for the regex.  So, `\x22` instead of `\"`.  None of those other characters need escaping.

Comment: @AlanMoore is correct..you have to use `\x22` instead of `\"`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `pattern=\"[^!#$%^&*'|"]{8}\"`

You should **escape literal double quote** outside `[]` instead of inside.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/uP5pC6/1

Comment: thanks! but this doesn't allow email? why? I want to allow everything, except ^!#$%^&*'|

Comment: I think it's because the email is longer than 8 characters. `{8}` only allow exactly 8. If you want 8 or more, use `{8,}`

Comment: nope, i tried doing the {8,} and even doing {8,100} still didn't accepted my input which is an email

Comment: I should see the exact string. Please update your question

Comment: I actually just copied yours, and added the  {8,} and also tried {8,100}.. pattern=\"[^!#$%^&*'|"]{8,}\"

Comment: Not that string. I mean the HTML with email

Comment: you mean the input? or the exact html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110091/discussion-between-aminah-nuraini-and-jc-borlagdan).